# C# Excel - save each worksheet to a new workbook

Tags: c#, excel

I have an excel with 25 or so worksheets I just want to save each worksheet as it's own new Workbook.  When I run the code it copys the entire workbook just not the individual sheet.  Any help would be awesome.

```
string FileDropLocation = @"C:\ExcelFiles";
        string file_FullFileName = @"C:\ts\Conversion\v2.xlsx";
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workBook = app.Workbooks.Open(file_FullFileName, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < workBook.Worksheets.Count; i++)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet workSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workBook.Sheets[i+1];
            workSheet.SaveAs(FileDropLocation + "\\" + workSheet.Name);
        }
        workBook.Close();
```

Comment: You cannot call SaveAs on a worksheet - first call `.Copy` to create a standalone new workbook containing only that sheet, then save that workbook.

Comment: @TimWilliams can you please provide a code example?

Comment: Something along these lines - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283135/how-do-you-copy-an-excel-worksheet-into-a-new-workbook-and-bring-all-the-charts

Comment: @TimWilliams Yeah that example doesnt work it just holds the excel open

Comment: Sorry - I don't have any code that does what you need. Copy is the way to go though. Seemed like there were plenty of examples out there on Google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this in place of your current `for` loop and below

```
    foreach(Worksheet sheet in workBook.Worksheets)
    {
        var newbook = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
        sheet.Copy(newbook.Sheets[1]);

        newbook.SaveAs(FileDropLocation + "\\" + sheet.Name);
        newbook.Close();
    }

    workBook.Close();
```

Just to note, I believe `Workbooks.Add()` places in a default blank sheet (typically Sheet1), so if you want just the copied sheet you'll have to explicitly remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this works.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xl = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook wb = null;
            xl = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            xl.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1;
            xl.Visible = true;
            wb = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)(xl.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing));

            wb.SaveAs(FileDropLocation + "\\" + workBook.Sheets[i + 1].Name, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel8, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            wb.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            xl.Quit();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook destWorkbook = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet workSheet = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet newWorksheet = null;

            destWorkbook = app.Workbooks.Open(FileDropLocation + "\\" + workBook.Sheets[i + 1].Name + ".xls", false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            workSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workBook.Sheets[i + 1];
            newWorksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)destWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            app.DisplayAlerts = false;
            workSheet.Copy(Type.Missing,newWorksheet);
            destWorkbook.Save();
```

Comment: Adding a `using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` at the top of your code will allow you to clean it up and make it far more readable.

Answer (score 0):

... You need to create a new workbook in your loop and move the sheet to that workbook.
I program in VB, so i'm guessing, but the code inside your foor loop should look something like this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workBook2 = app.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value)
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet workSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workBook.Sheets[i+1];
workSheet.Copy(workBook2.Sheets(1))
```

Then you can add code to delete the other sheets, etc.

Hope tihs helps.