# Worksheet.SaveAs Method Saves All Sheets

Tags: c#, excel

Using C# to write a method that takes a single worksheet out of a workbook and saves it as HTML.

I am using the Worksheet.SaveAs method as described on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.saveas(v=vs.110).aspx).

However, when I look at the output it has gone and saved all of the worksheets within the workbook, not just the one I selected. It's as though Worksheet.SaveAs and Workbook.SaveAs just do the same thing.

Simplified code:

```
public static void saveSingleSheetAsHTML(string workbook, string destination, string sheetName)
{
    Application excel = new Application();
    excel.Workbooks.Open(Filename: workbook);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = excel.Worksheets[sheetName];
    var format = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlHtml;
    worksheet.SaveAs(destination, format);
}
```

Now when I open the resulting HTML file it has only gone and exported the entire workbook, not the sheet.

Comment: I think something along the lines of this post should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734578/c-sharp-excel-save-each-worksheet-to-a-new-workbook Basically copies the worksheet to a new workbook and you can then save it from the new workbook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said by [Tim Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734578/c-sharp-excel-save-each-worksheet-to-a-new-workbook#comment20616297_14734578) in a comment I found after hitting a link posted by [I love my monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666210/worksheet-saveas-method-saves-all-sheets/25666737#comment40108715_25666210) above:

> "You cannot call SaveAs on a worksheet - first call .Copy to create a
>   standalone new workbook containing only that sheet, then save that
>   workbook."

No idea why you cannot. The docs on MSDN do not give any clue about this and suggest it should be possible.

So having created a new workbook:

```
var newbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(1);
```

Copy the sheet over, which will place it as the first sheet:

```
excelWorksheet.Copy(newbook.Sheets[1]);
```

Then delete the default "Sheet1", which will always be the 2nd sheet:

```
newbook.Worksheets[2].Delete();
```

Then call the SaveAs method and then close the new book:

```
newbook.SaveAs(Filename: destination, FileFormat: format);
newbook.Close();
```

This did save the new workbook as HTML, but also put the tabs at the bottom, which I was hoping to avoid as there is only 1 tab now. It does meet my minimum needs, though I would like to figure out how to make it a bit neater.