# Saving excel single sheet

Tags: vb.net, excel

Sorry for bad English

I can save Excel file, but when saved, the file has all sheets, not only "NaCl", but also all sheets are saved to new file. This is my code.

I want to save a new file with single sheet. Thanks

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\งาน\งานโปรเจคปี 3\sa\Sourcecode_VB\project1\project1\excel\test_excel.xlsx")
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("NaCl")
With xlWorkSheet
    '~~> Directly type the values that we want
    .Range("D8").Value = "1"
    .Range("D9").Value = "2"
End With

xlWorkBook.SaveAs(Filename:="D:\งาน\งานโปรเจคปี 3\sa\Sourcecode_VB\project1\project1\excel\test_excel1.xlsx", FileFormat:=51, _
     ReadOnlyRecommended:=True, CreateBackup:=False)
```

Comment: If you open Excel file manually, and then go to File-Save As, will it save only one sheet? - I don't think so. I don't see anything in your code that will make only one sheet being saved. This means, you have to create new book and copy your sheet to it. Ok, here is your answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14736425/1704458 - I will mark your question as duplicate

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Excel - save each worksheet to a new workbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734578/c-sharp-excel-save-each-worksheet-to-a-new-workbook)

Answer (score 0):

I can only tell the solution using native VBE. You'll need to delete the worksheets, **make sure you change the save path**.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'removes delete prompts
For Each ws In xlWorkBook.Worksheets
    If ws <> xlWorkSheet Then ws.Delete 'deletes each worksheet that's not NaCl
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```