# How to convert Excel file with multiple sheets to a set of TSV files?

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net, ssis, vb.net-2010

What addition clde to be added to cconvert excel file with multiple sheets to Tsv file in the below code.

note:The below code convert an excel file with one sheet to Tsv.It does not handle an excel sheet with multiple sheet

```
Public Sub Main()

        Dim oExcel As Object
        Dim oBook As Object

        Dim sFileName As String
        Dim sFileNameOnly As String


        Dim sXlsPath As String
        Dim sTsvPath As String



        sFileName = CStr(Dts.Variables("User::Xls_File_Name").Value)


        sXlsPath = "H:\Xls_Files\" + sFileName

        sFileNameOnly = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sFileName)

        sTsvPath = "H:\Xls_Files\" + sFileNameOnly + ".Txt"


        oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")


        oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(sXlsPath)

        oBook.SaveAs(sTsvPath, -4158)

        oBook.Close(False)
    enter code here
        oExcel.Quit()

        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
    End Sub
```

Comment: One possibility would be to create a scratch workbook, [copy each sheet to it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734578/c-sharp-excel-save-each-worksheet-to-a-new-workbook), save it to `tsv` then once complete, discard it without saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` for that task (note that you need to reference that namespace first).

as @stuartd suggest you can create a summary worksheet that will contain all the sheets according to your sheets structure (please see my comment inside the code)
or alternatively (if it suits your needs) you can save each worksheet on a different tsv file using the `For Each` loop.
here is a tested example that shows the principle of that:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

     Public Sub Main()
            Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
            Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
            Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
            xlApp.Visible = False

            ' create a new workbook (you can open existing workbooks using the Open() method) '
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
            ' create sheet 1 '
            xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Add()
            xlWorkSheet.Name = "ws1"
            xlWorkSheet.Range("a1").Value = "hello from worksheet1"
            ' create sheet 2 '
            xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Add()
            xlWorkSheet.Name = "ws2"
            xlWorkSheet.Range("a1").Value = "hello from worksheet2"
            ' worksheet that contain both worksheets '
            xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Add()
            xlWorkSheet.Name = "summary"

            ' paste all sheets data inside the summary sheets (i dont know how your excel sheets are structured but you can select entire ranges and arrange them on the summary worksheet) '
            Dim counter As Int16 = 1
            For Each w As Worksheet In xlWorkBook.Worksheets
                If w.Name <> "summary" Then
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells(counter, 1) = w.Range("a1")
                    counter += 1
                End If
            Next
            xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
            ' save as tsv file '
            xlWorkBook.SaveAs("c:\xxx\xxx\Book4.tsv", XlFileFormat.xlTextWindows, CreateBackup:=False)
        End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this.So,the code expecting the name of all sheets prior to executing the code?

Comment: I am using Micrsoft Visual basic 2012 in SSIS(script task).When I use the below import,it shows ,name space in the imports ,  Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
    Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel do not contain any public memebr

Comment: a reference from *com section* inside references was added? in other words did you made that: right click on project>>add reference>>click on COM>>check Microsoft Excel x.0 Object Library >>OK ?

Comment: yes ,there is no such Microsoft Excel x.0 Object Library  !!

Comment: ok now i see you are using ` Micrsoft Visual basic 2012 in SSIS` i never used visual basic on ssis but i guess its not flexible as visual studio, cant you use vb.net using visual studio? also found that: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4c409d02-2bf2-429f-b93f-dac4f02cc1f0/using-and-disposing-excel-interop-assembly-with-vbnet-in-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: The thing is the script is as a part of the ETL flow!

Comment: so you can use the same logic with the "VBA LIKE" syntax you wrote in the question, but remember to kill each process using `oExcel.Quit()` and declaring a new application on each workbook you open